# How do i disable submenu links in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, submenu

As soon as you create a menu item for a page there is a link that it automatically populated with it. How do i stop wordpress from making these links? I'm capable of making them myself and don't always want them to link to thier specific page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using and dropping it in my header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$("li.menu-item-627,li.menu-item-14,li.menu-item-20,li.menu-item-28").children("a").attr('href', "javascript:void(0)");
});
</script>
```

You have to use firebug or chrome "inspect element" to find out what your menu items are and then just replace the numbers in the code accordingly.

also if you don't want them to show up at all add the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function($) { $("li.menu-item-627").contents().hide();});</script>
```

those two together will hide the disabled menu link

you can then add your own links in the "navigation label" of the page menu field!

good luck and let me know if you have any questions, i will do my best to help!